# $T: \mathbb C ^{n \times n} \to \mathbb C ^{n \times n}$ defined by $T(A)=BA$, so every eigenvalue of $T$ is eigenvalue of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $T: \mathbb C ^{n  \times n} \to \mathbb C ^{n  \times n}$ defined by $T(A)=BA$.
>
> $A,B \in \mathbb C ^{n  \times n}$.
>
> Prove:
>
> 1. Every eigenvalue of $T$ is eigenvalue of $B$, and vice versa.
> 2. Geometry multiplicty of every eigenvalue of $T$ is $\le n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$, with eigenvector $A\ne0$: this means
$$
BA=\lambda A
$$
and, looking at $A$ as made of its columns $A=[v_1\ v_2\ \dots\ v_n]$ we see that
$$
Bv_i=\lambda v_i
$$
for $i=1,2,\dots,n$. Since $A\ne0$ at least one of its columns $v_j$ is nonzero. Thus $v_j$ is an eigenvector for $B$ relative to $\lambda$.

The second assertion is false. If $B$ is the identity matrix, the eigenspace of $T$ relative to $1$ has dimension $n^2$.